# react-google-maps zoom map to circle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

This is mainly a question about 'translating' JS to JSX.

I have a react-google-maps map which contains a marker, and a circle around that marker:

The Map component:

```
export class Map extends Component {
  render() {
    const GoogleMapInstance = withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultCenter = { { lat: parseFloat(this.props.lat), lng: parseFloat(this.props.lng) } }
        defaultZoom = { 16 }
        defaultOptions={{ styles: mapStyles }}
      >
        <Marker position={{ lat: parseFloat(this.props.lat), lng: parseFloat(this.props.lng) }}/>
        <Circle center={{ lat: parseFloat(this.props.lat), lng: parseFloat(this.props.lng) }} radius={parseFloat(this.props.accuracy)} options={{ fillColor: 'red', strokeColor: 'red' }}/>
      </GoogleMap>
    ))
    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMapInstance
          containerElement={ <div style={{ height: '600px', width: '100%' }}/> }
          mapElement={ <div style={{ height: '100%' }}/> }
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I would like the map to be zoomed such that the circle takes up about 50% of the map. I understand using the Javascript API, I can just do:

```
map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds())
```

But I'm not sure how to integrate that with the JSX that I have...

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
export class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.map = React.createRef()
    this.circle = React.createRef()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.map && this.circle) {
      const bounds = this.circle.current.getBounds()
      this.map.current.fitBounds(bounds)
    }
  }

  render() {
    const GoogleMapInstance = withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultCenter = { { lat: parseFloat(this.props.lat), lng: parseFloat(this.props.lng) } }
        defaultZoom = { 16 }
        defaultOptions={{ styles: mapStyles }}
        ref={this.map}
      >
        <Marker position={{ lat: parseFloat(this.props.lat), lng: parseFloat(this.props.lng) }}/>
        <Circle ref={this.circle} center={{ lat: parseFloat(this.props.lat), lng: parseFloat(this.props.lng) }} radius={parseFloat(this.props.accuracy)} options={{ fillColor: 'red', strokeColor: 'red' }}/>
      </GoogleMap>
    ))
    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMapInstance
          containerElement={ <div style={{ height: '600px', width: '100%' }}/> }
          mapElement={ <div style={{ height: '100%' }}/> }
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The `refs` create a way to access the `GoogleMap` and `Circle` nodes, and the `componentDidMount` is a lifecycle hook that lets you run the `fitBounds` call when the `Map` component is first rendered to the DOM.

Comment: This looks promising, but for some reason, the 'current' parameter of each ref is always null...

Comment: @Alex Sounds like your components either don't have the `ref` attribute set or are not getting rendered. It's been a minute since I've used `componentDidMount`, but I want to say that `render` is called before `componentDidMount` initially.

Comment: Hmm, I copied the code exactly as you wrote it, and the components are definitely rendered (I can see a map with a circle on it on my screen)

Comment: It's possible that the components aren't actually doing anything with the ref. You may want to [brush up on the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to see what you need.

Comment: I've read that page, and it seems fine, so the only thing I can imagine is that these are functional components, which don't have an instance...

Comment: React will usually complain in development if you're passing a ref to a functional component that isn't using forwardRef.

Comment: Oh, it’s not complaining... I have no idea. I’ve tried asking the gitter for the library, but it seems dead

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you could access native Google Map and Circle objects via [`Ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and manipulate it. But when it comes to getting map instance, prefer [Map `idle` event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.idle) over `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method to guarantee the map is ready, for example:

```
handleMapIdle() {
   const map = this.map.current; //get Google Map instance
   //...
}
```

where

```
 <GoogleMap
        ref={this.map}
        onIdle={this.handleMapIdle}
        ...
      >
      ...
 </GoogleMap>
```

Here is a modified Map component:

```
class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.map = React.createRef();
    this.circle = React.createRef();
    this.handleMapIdle = this.handleMapIdle.bind(this);
    this.idleCalled = false;
  }

  handleMapIdle() {
    if (!this.idleCalled) {
      const bounds = this.circle.current.getBounds();
      this.map.current.fitBounds(bounds);
      this.idleCalled = true;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const GoogleMapInstance = withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        ref={this.map}
        defaultCenter={{
          lat: parseFloat(this.props.lat),
          lng: parseFloat(this.props.lng)
        }}
        defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
        onIdle={this.handleMapIdle}
      >
        <Marker
          position={{
            lat: parseFloat(this.props.lat),
            lng: parseFloat(this.props.lng)
          }}
        />
        <Circle
          ref={this.circle}
          center={{
            lat: parseFloat(this.props.lat),
            lng: parseFloat(this.props.lng)
          }}
          radius={parseFloat(this.props.accuracy)}
          options={{ fillColor: "red", strokeColor: "red" }}
        />
      </GoogleMap>
    ));
    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMapInstance
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: "600px", width: "100%" }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qzzp5a)